# call one asynchronous function when the first one runs flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have two asynchronous functions, one returns a popup, the other makes a permission request. I call them in the init method. But they are called simultaneously, i.e. the first window appears and immediately the second. How do I fix this?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
final keyIsFirstLoaded = 'is_first_loaded';
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final context = MyApp.navKey.currentState.overlay.context;
       await showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context);
       await initPlatformState();
    });
  }
showDialogIfFirstLoaded(BuildContext context, prefs) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLoaded = prefs.getBool(keyIsFirstLoaded);
    if (isFirstLoaded == null) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return object of type Dialog
           return new AlertDialog(
                 // title: new Text("title"),
                 content: new Text("//"),
                 actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text(".."),
                    onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  prefs.setBool(keyIsFirstLoaded, false);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
initPlatformState() async {
    print('Initializing...');
    await BackgroundLocator.initialize();
    print('Initialization done');
    final _isRunning = await BackgroundLocator.isRegisterLocationUpdate();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = _isRunning;
    });
    onStart();
    print('Running ${isRunning.toString()}');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `return` to `showDialog` statement, you're not returning a `Future` so `await` isn't doing anything

Personal advice: always specify return types, cause if you don't, you get `dynamic` return type. If you do specify it, the IDE/dart analysis server will help you with problems such as this one.

Comment: how exactly I should add return? I return alert dialog

Comment: `return showDialog` - you're returning a widget from the anonymous function (`builder`), not from `showDialogIfFirstLoaded`